# Large deviations of binomial distribution

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability

Let $B(n,p)$ be a binomial distribution, where $p$ is fixed. Let $\varepsilon > 0$ be fixed and "small". I need a lower bound for the tail probability of this distribution, at distance $\varepsilon n$. It seems to me that for a random variable having this distribution one should essentially have
$$
P ( |X-np| \geq \varepsilon n) \gg e^{-\sigma^2 \varepsilon^2 n/2},
$$
where $\sigma^2$ is the variance. Can someone give me a reference for such an inequality?

(I suppose one could show this using heavy machinery, such as Kullback-Liebler distance etc., but it should be a simple and basic fact. Anyway, I have not found a reference. Thanks for your help.)

Comment: why don't you try $P(X-np = \epsilon n)$ which ought to be about the same size as the whole tail.   I'd suppose you could massage the single binomial probability into the form you wanted.

Comment: Yes, that should be possible, but it would probably take several lines in the paper. I would prefer to simply cite a reference. Actually, in my application it would be sufficient to have the lower bound $e^{-c(\varepsilon) n}$, where $c(\varepsilon) \to 0$ as $\varepsilon \to 0$.

Comment: Wikipedia has a lower bound: the last formula in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Tail_bounds

Comment: Yes, I saw that, but it is not quite explicit. To come to the conclusion that I would like to have one would have to linearize the Kullback–Leibler divergence, and that's exactly the sort of technical difficulties that I would prefer to avoid. I thought the desired result could just be stated somewhere as a lemma.

Comment: In section 2 of his "Potpourri" (https://cs.nyu.edu/spencer/papers/potpourri.pdf ) Joel Spencer describes situations under which you can say the exponent in the Chernoff bound is asymptotically optimal.  This might be usable for the sort of thing you're looking for

Answer (score 4):

What you need might be Slud's inequality: Let $B\sim B(n,p)$ be your binomial variable and $k$ be an integer such that either (i) $p\le1/4$ and $k\ge np$ or (ii) $p\le1/2$ and $np\le k\le n(1-p)$ holds. Then
$$ P(B\ge k) \ge P\left(N \ge \frac{k-np}{\sqrt{np(1-p)}}\right),$$
where $N\sim N(0,1)$ is the standard normal variable.
Reference:
https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aop/1176995801

Comment: Yes, thank you, this is what I want. The only drawback is that it does not give any result in the "fair" case $p=1/2$. So one would need an extra argument to cover that case.

Comment: Well, it does give *a* result, just not a very informative one -- it gives $P(B\ge n/2)\ge1/2$.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Lemma 1 (Section 2) in Connected components in random graphs with
given expected degree sequences by Fan Chung and Linyuan Lu, see [here](http://people.math.sc.edu/lu/papers/conn.pdf).

Comment: No, that's an upper bound for the tail estimate, but I was looking for a lower bound.

Comment: Argh, excuse me.

Comment: No worries, these things happen to all of us all the time.